# OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "Servername" returned message "No transaction is active."

Tags: sql-server, database, database-connection, sql-server-ce, database-administration

I have a database which is on another server. I created the linked server in my mssql and inserting data on a live database by firing the trigger whenever I insert data in my local database.
I also set configurations in MSDTC from component service and restart server and client many times

But still getting this error

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "Servername" returned message >"No transaction is active.

```
    USE HWMS
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.AshCollInsert    // trigger name
   ON  hwms.dbo.AshCollection       // local db table
   AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Just INSERT everything from the [inserted] pseudotable into
    --the target table
    INSERT INTO [ServerName].[HWMS].dbo.AshCollection2     // server db table 
              (id, UserId, IncinatorId,In_Weight,IncineratorCollectTime,Barcode,flex,flag)
        SELECT id, UserId, IncinatorId,In_Weight,IncineratorCollectTime,Barcode,flex,flag
        FROM   inserted;

END
GO
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need a bit more detail here. This is just a very vague overview of what you are doing. How about some code? Maybe some table definitions too.

Comment: I have one database at local and other database at server side. i created tables with same column names and data types in both databases and inserting data from local database to live database on triger when data is insert in local database in that table.
if still this is unclear plz ask.

Comment: How about some code? Maybe some table definitions too.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have attached my database trigger script in the question statement

Comment: How about the code that is doing the insert? Is there a transaction in that code? You have to provide details for others to be able to help here.